# How to write type definitions for function with optional argument?

Tags: typescript

Trying to write type definitions for [github-slugger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/github-slugger) to fix the following error.

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'github-slugger'.
>   '/Users/sunknudsen/Sites/sunknudsen/sunknudsen-website/node_modules/github-slugger/index.js'
>   implicitly has an 'any' type.   Try `npm install
>   @types/github-slugger` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts)
>   file containing `declare module 'github-slugger';`  TS7016

I only need to cover the `slug` function.

```js
/**
 * Generate a unique slug.
 * @param  {string} value String of text to slugify
 * @param  {boolean} [false] Keep the current case, otherwise make all lowercase
 * @return {string}       A unique slug string
 */
BananaSlug.prototype.slug = function (value, maintainCase) {
  var self = this
  var slug = slugger(value, maintainCase === true)
  var originalSlug = slug

  while (own.call(self.occurrences, slug)) {
    self.occurrences[originalSlug]++
    slug = originalSlug + '-' + self.occurrences[originalSlug]
  }

  self.occurrences[slug] = 0

  return slug
}
```

This is what I have so far (which works).

```js
declare module "github-slugger" {
  export function slug(string): string
  export function slug(string, boolean): string
}
```

Is this the right approach to handling optional arguments?

Comment: You may use the smaller Typescript fork https://github.com/Hocdoc/github-slugger-typescript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this:

```
declare module "github-slugger" {
  function slug(string: string, maintainCase?: boolean): string
}
```

Note that `function slug(string, boolean): string` is the same as `function slug(string: any, boolean: any): string`. In Typescript, the parameter names need to be specified.

For more info see [the documentation on optional and default parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#optional-and-default-parameters).

Comment: Thanks cherryblossom. Didn’t realize writing type definitions in `d.ts` were essentially the same as writing them in `ts` files. FYI, submitted an edit to fix a typo with `?`.